# Utilização do Watson da IBM com php e Curl

Tags: php, json, ibm

Bom dia, estou tentando utilizar o serviço de chatbot da IBM o watson.
Como teste criei o meu workflow de atendimento para um pedido simples de pizza.

Ao inicio do chamado ele da as boas vindas e pergunta qual pizza eu quero.

Ele valida 3 informações
1- Quantidade
2- sabor
3- se vai refrigerante junto

no teste do watson no painel web ele funciona o conversation perfeitamente como programei. mas quando dou a entrada no curl ele fica repetindo o start mesmo que eu responda as informações da mesma forma que eu fiz no input to chatweb teste do site da ibm

segue meu cod curl

```
    curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic NDkzYzBmZWItMzg2MC00O6RiLTkyMjUtM2E0ODc4MDMxODY3OmGFTFUzdUd1a0NDRg==' -d '{ \ 
   "input": { \ 
     "text": "" \ 
   }   \ 
 }' 'https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/9ec1ac11-786d-4c2d-9d8a-528265e3bcbb/message?version=2017-02-03'
```

e ele me devolve esse json

```
{
  "intents": [],
  "entities": [],
  "input": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "output": {
    "log_messages": [],
    "text": [
      "bem vindo a pizzaria smartphone. quantas pizzas o senhor deseja pedir hoje?"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "inicio"
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "conversation_id": "3f4b12da-2c3c-4b04-a94e-2da688ece806",
    "system": {
      "dialog_stack": [
        {
          "dialog_node": "inicio"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
      "dialog_request_counter": 1,
      "_node_output_map": {
        "inicio": [
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

como eu devo reenviar outra requisição para que ele continue na mesma conversação e não fique me mostrando novamente o inicio toda vez que faço o curl.

eu tentei enviar da seguinte forma e continua com problemas:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic NDkzYzBmZWItMzg2MC00O6RiLTkyMjUtM2E0ODc4MDMxODY3OmGFTFUzdUd1a0NDRg==' -d '{ \ 
   "input": { \ 
     "text": "quero uma pizza" \ 
   }, \ 
   "context": { \ 
     "conversation_id": "3f4b12da-2c3c-4b04-a94e-2da688ece806" \ 
    } \ 
 }' 'https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/9ec1ac11-786d-4c2d-9d8a-528265e3bcbb/message?version=2017-02-03'
```

e ele me retorna de novo o início:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "qtd-pizza",
      "confidence": 0.9523983001708984
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "qtd-pizza",
      "location": [
        6,
        9
      ],
      "value": "1",
      "confidence": 1
    },
    {
      "entity": "sys-number",
      "location": [
        6,
        9
      ],
      "value": "1",
      "confidence": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "numeric_value": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "input": {
    "text": "quero uma pizza"
  },
  "output": {
    "log_messages": [],
    "text": [
      "bem vindo a pizzaria smartphone. quantas pizzas o senhor deseja pedir hoje?"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "inicio"
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "conversation_id": "3f4b12da-2c3c-4b04-a94e-2da688ece806",
    "system": {
      "dialog_stack": [
        {
          "dialog_node": "inicio"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
      "dialog_request_counter": 1,
      "_node_output_map": {
        "inicio": [
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gostaria de uma orientação de como proceder. A leitura do json, curl e etc eu estou fazendo através de um php e apenas preciso de ajuda com a lógica de funcionamento do watson. Obrigado desde já pela atenção.

segue link da api do watson e a api explorer para testes online

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message

https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/conversation-v1#!/message/message

Comment: Coloca o link da API do Watson, por favor.

Comment: adicionei na postagem principal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá.
Não tenho certeza até o momento, mas acredito que o problema está no "context" da sua requisição.

Você deve salvar todo o context recebido na primeira resposta (incluindo conversation_id, system, dialog_turn_counter, dialog_request_counter e context vars caso possua) e então enviá-lo quando for fazer uma nova requisição.

No seu exemplo você está enviando o "context" apenas com o conversation_id.

Você pode ver exemplos disso na documentação, aqui:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/develop-app.html#maintaining-state

```
// Prompt for the next round of input.
var newMessageFromUser = prompt('>> ');
// Send back the context to maintain state.
conversation.message({
  input: { text: newMessageFromUser },
  context : response.context, <--- O context é devolvido da mesma forma que o Watson envia.
}, processResponse)
```

e aqui:https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#send_message